# phonegap remote build command "android" failed

Tags: android, cordova

I installed latest version of phonegap with npm, which shows version 4, and latest android sdk.
After creating simple myApp "hello world" project to test, I added android platform and can do local build and run the app with phonegap developer app on my phone.

But... if I do a remote phonegap build then the error log from build.phonegap.com  for this app shows 
'Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.'

I have JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME configured and ant and the android sdk tools and platform-tools are in my path.
I can execute android from cmd shell to bring up SDK Manager.

This is all on Windows 7 64 bit.
I'm probably missing something simple, but driving me nuts that I can't do a remote build.

Comment: I deleted the test app (locally and from build.phonegap.com), recreated it and then ran phonegap remote build android, and it worked.

So I'm thinking that when I first ran just the local build, and then tried to build remote afterwards, that doesn't work?  

Do I have to use just one or the other.
I was hoping I could test with developer app locally, and then later use remote build.  Bet I'm still missing something here, maybe a change to config.xml is needed when moving from local to remote?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there was a temporary problem with the phonegap build service, which is now working again.
Ah well...